# Magento 2.3 | Custom module with route but returns 404

Tags: magento2.3

Im currently working my first small custom module and followed some threads and docs to get to the point where im currently at. Goal of the module is the following:
• Create a custom route ( shopbycar/shopbycar/car )
• Get all prdocuts with attribute carId as List

Thats my current code, im pretty sure im missing somehting on the routes.xml...

`etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="shopbycar" frontName="shopbycar">
            <module name="Streetec_ShopByCar"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

---

`etc/module.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Streetec_ShopByCar" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

---

`Controller/ShopByCar/Car.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Streetec\ShopByCar\Controller\ShopByCar;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Car extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__constuct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $carId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('car_id');
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('car_id', $carId);
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle->set(__('Products by Car'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

---

`view/frontend/layout/shopbycar_car_index.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-left">
    <head>
        <title>Products by Car</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="car.products.list" template="Streetec_ShopByCar::product/list.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="is_car_page" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Based on Magento standards we would require 1 route in each module/extension. Can we have the reason behind creating 2 routes in a single module?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have two routes nested ? Is there a reason ? I think this is what is messing with your code; you should be creating `etc/frontend/routes.xml` to get a frontend route and you don't have to put a nested car route.

Just create your controller in the following location `Vendor/Controller/Car/Index.php`

The pattern is the following for a path : `routename/controllerFirstFolder/ControllerClassName`

So mapping `/shopbycar/car?var` is actually the same thing as mapping `/shopbycar/car/index?var`

which is why you need a route id shopbycar a controller namespace with car and a classname with index.

Index class name or package name can be omitted from url

THe url `/shopbycar` alone would match `Vendor\Controller\Index\Index.php`